# Values accepted in a tuple in swift

Tags: swift, tuples

I am a completely newbie in swift and in functional Programming.

My silly question is the following:

**Can a tuple return a set of functions?**
Is it a function like that accepted?

```
someFunction(param: Bool) -> ((Int) -> Int, (Float) ->Float) -> Double)
```

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Your specific example is not legal syntax, but it's not clear what you want the functions to be. In any case, yes, tuples can be of functions. What have you tried? Has it been a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a tuple of any type, and functions are types, so you can have tuples of functions.

For example, here’s a 2-tuple of two functions, one that takes two `Int`s and returns an `Int`, and one that takes two `Double`s and returns a `Double`:

```
// a 2-tuple of the addition functions for ints and doubles
let tupleOfFunctions: ((Int,Int)->Int, (Double,Double)->Double) = (+,+)
```

When you say, “can a tuple return a set of functions?”, I’m guessing you mean, “can a function return a tuple of functions?”.  And the answer is also yes:

```
func returnTwoFunctions(param: Bool) ->  ((Int,Int)->Int, (Double,Double)->Double) {
    // use the argument to drive whether to return some addition
    // or some subtraction functions
    return param ? (+,+) : (-,-)
}
```

Your example, though, is a bit scrambled – if you added a `func` keyword to the front, it’d be a function declaration, but you’ve got mismatched parentheses.  What it looks most like is a function (`someFunction`) that takes one boolean argument, and returns a function that itself takes two functions and returns a double:

```
func someFunction(param: Bool) -> (Int->Int, Float->Float) -> Double {
    let i = param ? 1 : 2
    // this declares and returns a function that itself takes two functions, 
    // and applies them to pre-determined number
    return { f, g in Double(g(Float(f(i)))) }
}

// h is now a function that takes two functions and returns a double
let h = someFunction(false)

// ~ and + are two unary functions that operate on ints and floats
h(~,+)  // returns -3.0  (which is  +(~2) )
```

Whether this is what you were intending, and whether you have a use-case for this kind of function, I’m not sure...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
The answers to your last sentence are YES and NOT YET respectively